# Playwright Lighthouse integration with TS: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require()

Tags: typescript, playwright, lighthouse, playwright-lighthouse

I'm trying to integrate **Lighthouse** tests in **Playwright** with **playwright-lighthouse** package.
Unfortunately I get this error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\lighthouse\core\index.js from C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\playwright-lighthouse\src\task.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\playwright-lighthouse\src\task.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Having project like:
`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "pw-lhc-tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.30.0",
    "lighthouse": "^10.0.1",
    "playwright-lighthouse": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

And the test `example.spec.ts`:

```
import { test } from '@playwright/test';
import { playAudit } from 'playwright-lighthouse';

test('has title', async ({ playwright }) => {
  
  const browser = await playwright['chromium'].launch({
    args: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222'],
  });
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://angular.io/');

  await playAudit({
    page: page,
    port: 9222,
  });

  await browser.close();
});
```

Error occure after running: `npx playwright test`

Full stacktrace:

```
 Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\lighthouse\core\index.js from C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\playwright-lighthouse\src\task.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\playwright-lighthouse\src\task.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
   at example.spec.ts:4

  2 | import { playAudit } from 'playwright-lighthouse';
  3 |
> 4 | test('has title', async ({playwright}) => {
    |                             ^
  5 |
  6 |   const browser = await playwright['chromium'].launch({
  7 |     args: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222'],
 
 at t.<computed>.tu._extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\utilsBundleImpl.js:16:1010)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\playwright-lighthouse\src\task.js:2:23)
    at t.<computed>.tu._extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\utilsBundleImpl.js:16:1010)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\playwright-lighthouse\src\audit.js:1:24)
    at t.<computed>.tu._extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\utilsBundleImpl.js:16:1010)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\playwright-lighthouse\index.js:1:23)
    at t.<computed>.tu._extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\utilsBundleImpl.js:16:1010)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\pw-lhc-tests\tests\example.spec.ts:4:29)
    at A._compile (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\utilsBundleImpl.js:16:994)
    at t.<computed>.tu._extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\utilsBundleImpl.js:16:1010)
    at requireOrImport (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\transform.js:192:12)
    at TestLoader.loadTestFile (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\testLoader.js:53:44)
    at loadTestFilesInProcess (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\testLoader.js:87:40)
    at Runner._loadTests (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\runner.js:294:51)
    at Runner._createFilteredRootSuite (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\runner.js:239:39)
    at Runner._collectTestGroups (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\runner.js:226:34)
    at async Runner._run (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\runner.js:345:9)
    at async TimeoutRunner.run (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\playwright-core\lib\utils\timeoutRunner.js:46:14)
    at async raceAgainstTimeout (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\playwright-core\lib\utils\timeoutRunner.js:90:15)
    at async Runner.runAllTests (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\runner.js:143:20)
    at async runTests (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\cli.js:165:18)
    at async ji.<anonymous> (C:\pw-lhc-tests\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\cli.js:71:7)
```

OS: Windows 11, Node 18

Project created with defaults after running: `npm init playwright@latest` so is in TypeScript

Tried couple of ideas form SO regarding `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require()` but nothing works.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like  `"lighthouse": "10.0.1"` is incompatible with `playwright-lighthouse` package.

To solve this issue stick with: `lighthouse@9.6.8`

Just:

```
npm install lighthouse@9.6.8
```

And tests should pass.

Watch issue and linked feature for update for integration with newest lighthouse:
https://github.com/abhinaba-ghosh/playwright-lighthouse/issues/45

Comment: Issue looks resolved with version 3.0.0 release 27/03/2023

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue with lighthouse@10.0.1, try to upgrade playwright-lighthouse version (install playwright-lighthouse@3.0.0 compatible with Lighthouse v10 ):

```
 npm install playwright-lighthouse@3.0.0
```

and add in your **package.json** :

```
  "type": "module",
```

Used to specify that the package is using ECMAScript modules instead of CommonJS modules. You can use import in your JavaScript code instead of require().

Tests should pass.